# This expression is not callable error when declaring stripe function

Tags: javascript, typescript, stripe-payments

I am receiving this error:

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'typeof import("stripe")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

When trying to call stripe and use the `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`. Here is the code I'm getting the error on:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```

the `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` is saved in the .env file. At first I thought there was a conflict with the stripe version I had downloaded but I don't believe that was the issue. I'm also confused why the error is a typescript error when I'm working in JavaScript.

I have tried downloading different versions of stripe and node.js, and trying to find if I have any typescript config files causing the issue but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

When TypeScript used, Stripe should be imported as a default import. For example:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...', {
  apiVersion: '2022-11-15',
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage-with-typescript