# This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import("stripe")' has no call signatures

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stripe-payments, strapi

I’m attempting to integrate Stripe with Strapi. I have this line of code in my project:

```js
const stripe = require(“stripe”)(“secret-key”);
```

However, I’m encountering an error message that says, ‘This expression is not callable. Type ‘typeof import(“stripe”)’ has no call signatures.’ Can you please help me identify and fix the issue to resolve this error?"

*I’m using javaScript not TypeScript

Comment: Does it work when you run the code.

Comment: Are you using the Plugin from Strapi, https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-stripe? Can you share way more details here?

Comment: @kelsny Other functionalities, such as data fetching, continue to work normally. I haven't written all the code related to the payment part yet; I just want to require the Stripe dependency. However, it shows me an error, so I didn't proceed further

Comment: @pgs First, I didn't use the plugins from Strapi; I just installed Stripe using npm. However, when I tried to use the plugins, I still encountered the same error. I've seen many tutorials where they implement Stripe like this: const stripe = require("stripe")("secret-key"); without adding any extra plugins, and it works fine. I'm not sure what's missing in my case. I've even tried reinstalling my dependencies, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I see a similar ask here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585279/this-expression-is-not-callable-error-when-declaring-stripe-function can you try the recommendation from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have experienced a temporary issue with my development environment, specifically Visual Studio, which sometimes  show  errors  in code that aren't really there.
The fact that the error disappeared after a while is a strong indicator that it might have been a temporary glitch or confusion in my code editor.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...');
```

[This link helped me](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)